# How to update node and npm in VS2015?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, nuget-package

I am using visual studio in order to develop an MVC Angular2 project.

When I change a dependencies in package.json, I got errors. The main one, I think is

```
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
```

Full log below.
I have been trying to update both via the NuGet Package Manager, the command or direct install.
Nothing works. I still have the same error and it seems that VS2015 is still using old version of Node and NPM.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Stéphane.

```
npm WARN package.json aspnet@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ie-shim
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-server
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-server
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rxjs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zone.js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ie-shim
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/common
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 'angular/common' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'aspnet'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\\\node\\node" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\Extensions\\Microsoft\\Web Tools\\External\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\plach\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Angular2Mvc5Application1\Angular2Mvc5Application1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.31
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code E404
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/compiler
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/http
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-server
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/core
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/router
npm

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the Node.js version which Visual Studio 2015 from "**Tools > Options**  menu and  **Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools**  tab. You should add your Node.js intallation folder (For example: ***C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs***). Make sure that your added folder top of older (default) Node.js folder. And lastly it needed restart of Visual Studio 2015.

For more details you can check [here](https://ryanhayes.net/synchronize-node-js-install-version-with-visual-studio-2015/).

Answer (score 3):

Found a great answer in the Developer Tools Blog :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/03/19/customize-external-web-tools-in-visual-studio-2015/

Since the desired node.js version was already installed globally, all I had to do was to change the order of the external tools path, so VS will search the $(PATH) first, and make it look like that:

[image: The external tools order]